# Wordpress meta_query error

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a athlete profile page and want to get entries from a results page to populate on the athlete page by athlete name. Here is the meta_query I am using:

```
        <?php
          $args = array(       
            'post_type' => 'result',
            'category_name' => 'results',
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order'   => 'ASC',
            'posts_per_page'  =>  '15',
            'paged'             =>  $paged,
            'meta_query' => array(
                         array(
                              'key'     => 'result',
                              'value'   => 'result-athlete',
                              'compare' => '='
                          ),
                      ),
            );
          $the_query = new WP_Query( $args );       

        ?>
```

I am getting the error:

> Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' ....  on line 98
>   Errors parsing
>   (line 98 has -  array(

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I don't think the two  last comma are required.  `),`

Comment: I have deleted the two comma's but still getting the error: Parse error: parse error, expecting `')'' .... on line 98

Still not sure what I am missing.

Comment: I am not at my computer that i can give this a try but could it be because the number in the posts_per_page has single quotes around it? I can try it tonight.